# Apache Camel error handler : Spring DSL

Tags: apache-camel

I have a question about adding an Apache Camel error handler to my config. I think I am doing something very silly that is probably a basic mistake.

I want to add two types of error handling...

```
<camel:errorHandler id="errorHandler" type="DefaultErrorHandler"
    <camel:redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="0"/>
</camel:errorHandler>
```

and

```
<onException>
    <exception>java.sql.SQLException</exception>
    <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="0"/>
    <to uri="log:xml?level=ERROR"/>
</onException>
```

Every time I add these to my context xml files the xml editor in Eclipse tells me that I have invalid XML content. I must be missing a namespace or something. For the first type of catch all exceptions I am placing that outside my camel context to then reference errorHandlerRef. For the 2nd type of error handling specifically to catch sql exceptions I am placing that in the route itself.

Here is my XML declaration.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
```

Can anyone shed some light here pls... thanks

Comment: Did you get this to work? Is it just Eclipse complaining? If you run the application does it startup and work? And in Eclipse maybe its cache of the namespace is old. There should be a way of reconfigure that etc.

Comment: Hi Yes, Sorry i made a couple of silly mistakes causing this not to work. I figured out that onException needs to go after the from in the route.

Comment: If I have three sql statements in my route do I only need to specify OnException once in the route or do I need to specify after every sql statement?

Comment: also to prevent camel from retrying after failure is maximumRedeliveries="0" correct? That does not seem to be working for me.

Comment: onException can be configured on both camelContext and route level. And Camel picks from route first, and fallback to camelContext level. You only need to configure onException once in the route. I suggest to read more about Camel error handling from the Camel web site / Camel books etc to better understand this.

Comment: I would suggest buying the book it is really awesome. Mine is all dog eared and abused by my carrying it around where ever I go.

Comment: Lol. Yep got a copy today. Really good content... Thks